# Upload snapshot artifact to Nexus Repository Manager

Tags: upload, nexus, snapshot

The 3rd party repository is generated by Nexus by default. I can deploy release artifact to the 3rd party, but it doesn't support uploading of snapshots.
[image: release repository]

I created another hosted repository "tecentRepository" to support snapshots, but there is no "Artifact Upload" tab anymore with snapshots.

[image: snapshot repository]

How can I manually upload an artifact with snapshot support?

Answer (score 5):

Manual upload to snapshot repositories is not supported. It is typically only done via build tools such as Apache Maven.

Comment: upload to release repository is also not supported, if the repository is created by myself. Only the 3rd party repository can success which is created by Nexus by default

Comment: This is not correct @maomao . As long as the user you login with has the the correct privileges any Maven2 format repository with a release policy will have the upload artifact tab. Try by using the admin account.